# IIS Express singleton session handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis-express

I'm new to asp.net mvc and I've started to develop an application with VS 2013 + IIS Express. I'm using `Session_start()` in `global.asax` to call a singleton/multiton object, that does some SQL-queries. I do want to have this object initialized only once for each user session, so I'm saving it into the Session and check every time if it's already there.

```
public static SingletonObject Instance{
get {
     string name = "so_set";
     if (HttpContext.Current.Session[name] == null)
         HttpContext.Current.Session[name] = new SingletonObject ();
            return (SingletonObject)HttpContext.Current.Session[name];
        }
    }
```

I've found this code at http://samcogan.com/singleton-per-asp-net-session/

When I'm debugging using Internet Explorer it is ok, because each time I close the tab VS stops debugging. But when I'm using Firefox, closing the tab doesn't stop the debugging process and I have to manually stop it in Visual Studio. Often I just leave the tab open and stop the debugging in VS, but when I start the debugging process again, a new tab opens - which leads to strange behaviour. This time it somehow "recovers" also the old tab and this singleton implementation doesn't work properly. It will call the private constructor twice - I added some console output into the private constructor to make it clear:

```
time: 04.02.44.008993
time: 04.02.44.009992
sessionID: l1dh4dghgk2urlpk3wu5xfmf
sessionID: l1dh4dghgk2urlpk3wu5xfmf
```

each "forgotten" tab generates an additional call. I'm checking the `sessionID` using

```
HttpContext.Session.SessionID
```

Even when I write something into the current session in the first line of `Session_Start` and check it before calling the constructor, it still manages to go inside - it somehow starts multiple times with the same `sessionID` (but there is still only one worker process visible in the task manager). Any ideas how to fix this?

Greetings
Martin

Comment: Add a lock around the contents of the getter.

Comment: sadly still the same thing happening, even with a lock in the constructor. I can't reproduce this issue on a test IIS server (not IIS Express, a "normal" one) so I'm not sure if this is a real issue or just some weird IIS Express behavior.